# Function composition on finite set is identity function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a finite set and $f: X \to X$ a bijective function.

Show that there exists a natural number $n \ge 1$ so that $f^n = \text{id}_X$ where $f^n := \underbrace{f \circ f \circ \ldots \circ f}_{n \text{ times}}$.

Intuitively I can explain it: Since $f$ is bijective every element of $X$ is uniquely mapped onto every element of $Y$ (here $X$). So because $X$ is finite, there are only finitely many possible combinations in which the elements can be mapped. Now if I repeatedly apply $f$ on an input, there must come a point where the second latest output is so that applying the function once more gives exactly the original input again. Since there are only finitely many combinations in which the elements can be mapped the function needs to be applied repeatedly only finitely many times.

Is my intuition correct? And how would one prove it actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right, but perhaps incomplete. How do you know that you can't get trapped in some kind of "cycle" that never gets you back to the starting point? (It's true that you can't, but why?)

As for how to prove it, here are some hints: since $X$ is finite, there are only a finite number (say, $m$) of bijections of $X$ to itself. So, consider the collection of functions $f, f^2, f^3, \dots, f^{m+1}$. By the pigeonhole principle, two of those must in fact be the same function. Use this fact, along with the fact that every bijection has an inverse, to make a conclusion.

Comment: Thanks! What are the pigeons and what are the wholes exactly? Why do two of those functions of the collection must be the same because can’t they have a cycle as you said?

Comment: The pigeons are "bijections of $X$ to itself," and the holes are "symbols $f^i$". You're not supposed to use the fact that they can't have a cycle; instead, that will be a consequence of the argument you will make.

Comment: My try: Since $|X|:=n \lt \infty$ there exists only finitely many distinctive bijective functions, let's say $m$. Let $f$ be one of them. If $f = \text{id}_X$ we're done. $f \neq \text{id}_X$ then $f \circ f \neq f$ and therefore $f^2$ is one of the remaining $m-1$ bijections. Since the mapping instructions of $f$ doesn't change if we apply it repeatedly also $f \circ f \circ f \neq f \circ f$ so $f^3$ is one of the remaining $m-2$ bijections. So it follows that $f^m = f$ and because of that there must have been some $k$ in between so that $f^k = \text{id}_X$.

I'm not at all sure about it.

Comment: I think you're still missing the key detail here. In particular, it does *not* follow directly from what you've said that $f^m = f$. All we can get from the pigeonhole principle is that $f^i = f^j$ for some distinct $i$ and $j$. What can we conclude from that fact? (Again, recall that $f$ has an inverse....)

Comment: Thanks, I think I get the second part, namely that if $i > j$ then $\text{id}_X = \underbrace{f^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \ldots \circ f^{-1}}_{i \text{ times}} \circ \underbrace{f \circ f \ldots \circ f}_{i \text{ times}} = \underbrace{f^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \ldots \circ f^{-1}}_{i \text{ times}} \circ \underbrace{f \circ f \ldots \circ f}_{j \text{ times}} = f^{j-i}$ and if $j > i$ then the other way around. But how do I know that $f^i = f^j$ for some $i, j$ in the first place? I think I don't see the pigeonhole principle here clearly...

Comment: Oops -- above, I gave you bad information about the pigeonhole principle. The pigeons are actually the symbols $f^i$, and the pigeonholes are the bijections. Since there are only $m$ bijections, but we have $m+1$ symbols in our list, two of them must actually be the same. (Sorry about that! I shouldn't answer questions before having coffee.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67716/discussion-between-philmcole-and-aaron-montgomery).

Comment: I think I've got it now! Can you take a look at my proof again in the chat (because it's to long for a comment)? Thank you very much!